# Arabic characters are coming wrong in downloaded excel

Tags: javascript, excel, arabic

I am trying to export data to excel in Javascript. Below is the code that I used:

```
var createAndExport = function(data){
            var table = "<table><thead><tr><td>";
            var head = Object.keys(data[0]);
            for(var i=0;i<head.length;i++){
                table += head[i]+"</td><td>";
            }
            table += "</td></tr></thead><tbody>";
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                table += "<tr>";
                for(var j=0;j<head.length;j++){
                    table += "<td>"+data[i][head[j]]+"</td>";
                }
                table += "</tr>";
            }
            table += "</tbody></table>";
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8,'+ table;

            var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            downloadLink.href = uri;
            downloadLink.download = "data.xls";

            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        }
```

This code working fine and downloading the data as excel. But the issue is data containing arabic words, that is appearing as some other characters in dowloaded excel as in the image. [image]

How can I fix this issue of arabic words?

Comment: Excel is not good to dealing with UTF-8, try csv

Comment: `table` is a JavaScript string encoded in UTF-16, which has not been converted into any kind of utf-8 octet sequence. Does `charset=utf-16` work any better?

Comment: utf-16 also giving the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encoding informations needs to be in the `HTML`template too:

```
var createAndExport = function(data){
            var table = "<head><meta charset='UTF-8'></head><table><thead><tr><td>";
...
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3fohpL9u/2/

Comment: Its woking!! Thank you @Axel